# Share good examples of Web-GUIs

Tags: user-interface, usability

I am probably at the edge of etiquette here since the question is somewhat subjective, and not stricly about programming, but **usability** - but in the end, what is more important than the usability of the solutions we create?

The idea is to **"work backwards" from usability to technology**:

*I want to see an impressive Web-GUI (show URL if possible) and then learn what technology enabled it.*

Comment: What does the underlying tech have to do with the usability?

Comment: In my view technology should be judged based on the usability it allows developers to provide users. Hence I find that going from a good solution back to its implementation is a way to show what technology "is more equal than others".

Comment: But, a well designed site could be built on crappy tech and equally a ugly site could be built on amazing tech.

Comment: @Tom: correct. But usability is not technology dependent from the users perspective. From a developer or dev company perspective, technology can become a usability issues again. e.g. what dev skills do we have? what IDE/tech supports these skills to develop a solution effectively, efficiently and to our/clients' satisfaction.
@Glytzhkof: you are suggetsing a user-centred approach which is central to usability engineering. If you focus on user needs, the context of use and design a solution appropriately - you can then more effectively choose an appopriate technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://stackoverflow.com  :)

never seen such a usable site

They are using:

- Framework: ASP.NET
- Language: C#
- Dev Environment: Visual Studio 2008
- Browser Framework: jQuery
- Database: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: I agree, it really is a uniquely designed system. Great focus on content - the bells and whistles help make the content better instead of just providing eye-candy. I am particularly impressed by the fact that I am writing this using Opera 10. The site looks perfectly even in Opera.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at jquery there's a lot of sites (amazon, google, IBM) using this framework this works pretty fine and also has a lot of plugins that make your life easier. If you want an impressive UI I think you need to take a look to it.

Here is the link if you want to check some sites using Jquery http://docs.jquery.com/Sites_Using_jQuery

Answer (score 1):

The guys at [37signals](http://37signals.com/) do a pretty good job at this.

Comment: Personally, I'd disagree, as I can't work out from their homepage what they are or what they do in less than 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Usability is technology independent largely.

Usability is about human factors, user centred design, user performance. The best websites and technology are the one which allow users to perform at an optimum level, achieving their task objectives within a context they understand (i.e. language, culture, etc.)

A list of URL's for examples of goo dusability is nice. But please don't take their design and implement it in some other context and think you are accommodating for good usability.

Focus on the task, context and user -> then design for that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Propably not what you are looking for but here it goes:

http://mail.google.com

Comment: This is a great GUI - I am just wondering what technology or framework was used to achieve it.