# What are some great web sites that are the best for the User Interface?

Tags: user-interface, usability

I am looking for nice looking sites that are good in terms of look and feel as well as usability.

Comment: Sounds very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059913/share-good-examples-of-web-guis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone had to say it: Stack Overflow!

Seriously - it may not be immediately beautiful to look at, but for what it is, and for its target audience and how they use it, it's a great example of both visual design and interaction design.

The layout, the use of colour, the sensible use of AJAX, the *lack* of fancy graphics, all give a good experience IMHO.

It's also a good example of how to incorporate advertising in an effective but unobtrusive way.

Comment: yes I would like other websites that have different business functions.

Answer (score 3):

Google.

It gets out of the way as much as possible and lets you focus on doing what you came there to do.

Comment: Until their last change a couple of days ago. Now it's ugly.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is question is much like [Share good examples of Web-GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059913/share-good-examples-of-web-guis) question that was post in the site sometime ago. probably it will help you.

Comment: it had the same answer -> Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

[Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) - beauty but especially showing you what different things can be done with pure accessible HTML. So having Usability in mind as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind/segment of site you want. But I`ll mention one that is kind of ***site to create site*** that helped me to create fast and beautiful things.

**[www.snappages.com](http://www.snappages.com/)** is a example of nice/easy/friendly/pretty/dummyFriendly/niceExamples/easyToCreatePrettyThings/easyToMaintain/etc...

I really think that is a *'must know place'*

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think gmail is an example of a very usable UI.

Comment: I see no point for downvoting this answer at all. Let me add a vote back.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found that other people's great web sites are more of an inspiration than a practical help.  Every site has particular needs.  For example, this site is good for what it does, but it really isn't a site I need to build; likewise for [this one](http://stuffwhitepeoplelike.com/) and [this one](http://whitestuffpeoplelike.wordpress.com/).

I think it is valuable to develop a philosophy/aesthetic for this, or at least be conversant with those who think a lot about design and accessibility.  Here are two sites with some serious discussion along these lines, along with some coding howto:

- http://stopdesign.com/
- http://www.456bereastreet.com/

But even these reflect my personal taste.  There are people in my family who really like Club Penguin.  And I hear some folks can tolerate MySpace.